# Prevent parent object to be saved when saving child object fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two associated classes like this:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :actions

  before_create do |p|
    self.actions.build
  end
end

class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :purchase

  before_save do |a|
    false
  end
end
```

The block in the `Action` class prevents it from saving. I was thinking doing `Purchase.create` will fail because it cannot save the child object. But while it does not save the `Action`, it commits the `Purchase`. How can i prevent the parent object to be saved when there is an error in the child object?

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you have to rollback the transaction explicitly, errors from the child objects does not propagate. So i ended up with:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :actions

  after_create do |p|
    a = Action.new(purchase: p)
    if !a.save
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
end

class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :purchase

  before_save do |a|
    false
  end
end
```

Take note that i also changed the `before_create` callback to `after_create`. Otherwise, since `belongs_to` also causes the parent to be saved, you will get a `SystemStackError: stack level too deep.`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem when dealing with race conditions where the child objects would pass a uniqueness validation, but then fail the database constraint (when trying to save the parent object), leading to childless (invalid) parent objects in the database.

A slightly more general solution to the one suggested by @lunr:

```rb
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :actions

  after_save do
    actions.each do |action|
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless action.save
    end
  end
end

class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :purchase

  before_save do |a|
    false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code in `Purchase` class:

```
validate :all_children_are_valid
def all_children_are_valid
  self.actions.each do |action|
    unless action.valid?
      self.errors.add(:actions, "aren't valid")
      break
    end
  end
end
```

Or use `validates_associated` in `Purchase` class:

```
validates_associated :actions
```

Answer (score 0):

If in your business logic you can't save purchase without any action, then add a presence validator on actions inside purchases

```
validates :actions, length: {minimum: 1}, presence: true
```